# где поставить запятые?

Tags: синтаксис

Цена литого наконечника для трубы диаметром 108 мм более 750 рублей.

Comment: Опять домашнее задание.

Comment: А почеу Вы решили, что здесь нужны запятые?!

Answer (score 2):

*Цена литого наконечника для трубы диаметром 108 мм — более 750 рублей.*

Answer (score 0):

Единственный осмысленный вариант с запятыми:

"Цена литого наконечника, для трубы диаметром 108 мм, (--) более 750 рублей".

В этом случае тире не обязательно. Но этот вариант очень и очень неестественный для подобного текста. В нем же нет уточнения как такового. Так что лучше без запятых, но с тире.

Comment: Запятые не нужны. Можно было поставить скобки там, где вы поставили запятые -- если бы не тире было, а глагол "составляет". А вот тире можно: оно заменяет пропущенный глагол.